# Conditional typing of a function based on another type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have defined a type as following:

```
type Criteria = 'Criterion A' | 'Criterion B';
type NoCriteria = 'NO CRITERIA';

type Props = {
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
} & (
  | {
      onChange: (
        event: MouseEvent,
        value: Criteria | NoCriteria | null,
      ) => void;
      value: Criteria | NoCriteria | null;
      nullable?: true;
    }
  | {
      onChange: (
        event: MouseEvent,
        value: Criteria | NoCriteria,
      ) => void;
      value: Criteria | NoCriteria;
      nullable: false;
    }
);
```

In this type the `value` can be `Criteria | NoCriteria` if `nullabe === false`, or, it can be also `null` when `nullable === true`, the same goes for the `value` type inside the `onChange`.

And then I have a component that uses this type as following:

```
const NullableComponent = ({
  label,
  value,
  onChange,
  required = false,
  nullable = true,
  disabled = false,
}: Props) => {

  const handleNoCriteriaToggleChange = (
    event: MouseEvent,
    newValue: 'NO CRITERIA' | null,
  ) => {
    if (!nullable) {
      onChange(event, 'No Criteria');
      return;
    }
    onChange(event, newValue ?? null);
  };

}
```

As you can see from this component the `nullable` prop is set to `true` so the onChange should evaluate to `onChange: (event: MouseEvent, value: Criteria | NoCriteria | null,) => void;`, but instead it evaluates to `onChange: (event: MouseEvent, value: Criteria | NoCriteria) => void`.

How can I solve this?

You can see more on this ts [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTgS2BRBDKBeKByeSUID2AdlAILZQA+OeyiJUAQtgNwBQokUAcoXQXRZsPAPKwASgEkAKgFFpFDp3DQACnEJgAzpigBvdlCgAbVACMIJgPwAuKNuCJiAcw7G4EAI4BXBJ4ATOyhzQkITCFRidygAhG0LCKD7UPDI6PYAXygAMigACiNqAyLjYxIYAAsolwh7QrLGqAgANwhiYHsAWUIfbQg5No6AGlKmltQTHzrYRHoEdBo+ATRi4h8TE1GmqABKTAA+KBbCBACYxompmZWF4uW5wTWNkwuy9c3EiGCnabfMoo0Qw7CrVVwzBo7ZpDTpQHp9AYw7ZQq7Tey3Ra8fiPNDIxr7DBHE5nN7GVE3HF3JbY-BoUlQD5mcwRewAM0m-X+7F2ynYAHoAFQCowCqCgmrQVqTHyoZC6YCEMXEKoS+qtdqw+H9QYa4bHaUU2lUrEYglE04BEVQADulXaUCQDkqvRMAWh0tl0AVSpV4LVMO6vW1SP113RlMxDyNmMZZuOFqt2gQxAAxtBGV8HaRgJV4lAU6h+g7dP1gFBvRnmRAML8ICK+ewUyRHLwXl8YIQALZgEgavT5YGmCxWZHk5Hi8HIzy+fwQN1YdkmfrIysRPS15FxBJV+dQRfLrL2DRabRxwxFJvEFtggIRKPzVAyQguFwRX21ftjdUdQMInUjMZiAga0ADUDXsERxBgaR5EUSgaEZZEzzGPk+QdVlyztTxiwZRVyXLRUUzBD8FT1UsCN4UQAH1oNkBQpDIdCGTbKscP3CA9UIHMUGteJoHIisXjGBAMPyABCVcIH2QdGgnWp8m-YA9UgyQ6Lgnkxg8CBgB8OAMkaAFZOVYiIAUkMgNAg0oGsaxmM2DTjEyZQAX5IUrWTTC8wgAAPVBuzXKRYhIbAywAa2IQhrSgZ0ou9AS7XLVQxQw7iGWAsDrgogADFTaNghj4LskwsqVEwQCYyScI3KAojdb0crEVT8ooEqRKKzM83Y+tG2bMs+GAHgWLfLseyAjp+0HJkRyKMcijkjiimnPxAj0diVyG6AFw5BbjC3L5dzWw8oGPHRkIvXrotqu8aQfJ8XzfEzP0aRTf2DXVAPS8CcEavL6IoZ5NiQw4SkaVCmO47C8wi0NpgooiJQIsjtIosQaJgv6Ko2tjts4iHeKLATFUZYTRIkjbpM0n0TLM3Vvqg9H1PpTwdL0rkjPfUzFL1CyMumByoCc9gsiAA)

Comment: @jcalz yes, sorry, it was a typo, I have updated the like to the playground

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring your types so that the behavior when `nullable` is omitted is specified in each case, possibly as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1Q3lw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, your solution works fine, thanks a lot, my only concern is that I need to initialize nullable = true, but as soon as I add that, i'm getting a typescript error, I'm afraid to say that it's mandatory to init nullable with true via props

Comment: ? Why do you need to initialize `nullable = true` when the code works the same as if it had been?  Can you show me with an example what goes wrong if you use my suggestion?  (because unfortunately [that's a limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266#issuecomment-1462630908) for this to work)

Comment: @jcalz I had no idea that was a limitation, thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: ... I'm trying to figure out if I should write up an answer or not.  As far as I can tell my suggestion works exactly how your original does, except that I'm using a computed `nullable ?? true` to simulate `nullable` being `true` if `undefined`, and `!nullable` which automatically behaves as if `nullable` is `false` if `undefined`.  Shall I write it up as an answer and note the limitation? Or is there something else that you need that doesn't work with this suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the default assignment for `nullable`.

Before Typescript 4.6, if you deconstruct `props`, `nullable` and `onChange` will become two separate variables, and there will no longer be any relationship between them. This situation is supported since 4.6, but default assignment cannot be made for deconstruction.

```js
const NullableComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    label,
    value,
    onChange,
    required = false,
    nullable,
    disabled = false,
  } = Object.assign(props, { nullable: props.nullable ?? true })

  const handleNoCriteriaToggleChange = (
    event: MouseEvent,
    newValue: 'NO CRITERIA' | null,
  ) => {
    // if there is no value to change to, set to NO_CRITERIA if nullable is false, otherwise set to null
    if (nullable === false) {
      onChange(event, 'NO CRITERIA');
      return;
    }
    onChange(event, newValue ?? null);
  };

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the problem with this solution is that `nullable`  is not set to true by default.

Comment: "If you [destructure] props, then `nullable` and `onChange` will become two separate variables, and there will no longer be any relationship between them." That isn't true; see [control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your correction. However, when deconstructing, assigning a default value to `nullable` does indeed lose its association with `onChange`.

Comment: Yes, [that's a limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266#issuecomment-1462630908).  But it's not the destructuring that's the problem there, it's the default value.

Comment: The key point is that TypeScript needs to distinguish the types of `props`, rather than distinguish the type of `nullable`. When assigning a default value to `nullable`, it may lose its association with `onChange`.